# getting the NAME of a select tag with javascript

Tags: html, vbscript

I haven't found this question anywhere so I'm posting it here.

I have a bunch of select tags that are partially named using VBScript.  I want to be able to get the name of a select tag that was called from the onchange event in javascript.

here is the code.

```
<select name="optWeeks_<%=intLineCnt%>" id = "name" onchange="changeWeek()">
       <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
</select>


<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">

function changeWeek(){
var chosenoption = document.getElementsByTagName("select").name

}
</SCRIPT>
```

The select name - `"optWeeks_<%=intLineCnt%>"` is optWeeks prefixed with a number

I would like to know if I can get each name of the select tag that is called?  Ex. optWeeks_1, optWeeks_2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the element. `this` will be one in your event handler function. You can pass it to the function you are calling from there:

```
onchange="var element = this; changeWeek(element)">
```

I included the variable assignment above for clarity, you don't need it:

```
onchange="changeWeek(this)">
```

You can then get the name from the `name` property on that object:

```
function changeWeek(element) {
    var name = element.name;
```

I'd generally recommend binding your event handlers with JS rather than HTML, not using HTML 3.2 though:

```
<select name="optWeeks_<%=intLineCnt%>" id="name">
    <!-- … -->
</select>

<script>
var select = document.getElementById('name');
select.addEventListener('change', changeWeek);
function changeWeek(evt) {
    var name = this.name;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I get the error 'name is null or not an object' - meaning element.name is null

Comment: I'm not sure where I am going wrong but I keep getting the same error, when I use your old style style example.

Comment: Since I can't see your attempt to implement it, I can't tell where you are going wrong.

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem, turns out it does not work in IE but works fine in Chrome.  Any ideas why it doesn't work in IE? And how can I get it to work with IE.  Thanks

Comment: It should all work fine in IE unless you are dealing in very old IE or you are in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

Answer (score 2):

Change the call to:

```
...  onchange="changeWeek(this);">
```

Then you can simply;

```
function changeWeek(caller) {
   var chosenoption = caller.name;
}
```

Comment: Typed it faster than I could.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
onchange="changeWeek(this.name)"
```

Or: (keep in mind that the changeWeek function will have to already have been defined)

```
    <script>
      var select = document.getElementById('name');
      select.onchange = changeWeek;
    </script>
```

[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) -- for information between adding event listeners and the method I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative JavaScript way:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

for(var i in selects)
{
    selects[i].onchange = function changeWeek(e) {console.log(e.target.name);}
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="test">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
</select>
<select name="test2">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bddwW/